# Printing the error in try catch block in powershell

Tags: exception, try-catch, powershell-3.0

Here is my script which returns a boolean

```
 param($fileName, $path, $contextMenuItem, $automationDLLPath)

 function CloseWindowsExplorer()
{
(New-Object -comObject Shell.Application).Windows() | foreach-object {$_.quit()}
}

Try
{ 

Import-Module $automationDLLPath

# Open the explorer window in a maximized form
Start-Process explorer $path -WindowStyle Maximized
Start-Sleep 1
Get-UIAActiveWindow

# Get the "Items View" in Explorer to go through all the lements
$list = Get-UIAList -Name 'Items View' -TimeOut 30000;

# Get the file specified in the feature file from the Items View 
# Added a sleep because the VM takes time to perform the functions
Start-Sleep 1
$file = $list | Get-UIAListItem -Name $fileName;

# Perform a single click on the file to invoke a right click on it
Invoke-UIAListItemSelectItem -InputObject $file -ItemName $fileName;

# Added a sleep because the VM takes time to perform the functions
Start-Sleep 1

# Invoke the right click on the selected file
$menu = Invoke-UIAControlContextMenu -InputObject $file;

Start-Sleep 1

# select our context menu item
$menuItem = Get-UIAMenuItem -InputObject $menu $contextMenuItem -TimeOut 30000;

# Display error if the required item in the context menu is not found
if( $null -eq $menuItem){
%{ Write-Host 'cannot find menuItem' }
}
# Invoke the item if found in the context menu
else{

Invoke-UIAMenuItemClick -InputObject $menuItem 
}

# close the windows explorer and return true   
CloseWindowsExplorer
Write-Output "true"
}

Catch
{ 
# close the explorer window as a part of teardown and return false to reflect test        failure 

Write-Output "false"

CloseWindowsExplorer
}
```

I want the script to print the exact exception that was caught as well as return a boolean but in this case it is just returning false when the script fails. Any help is appreciated
Basically I need to print the exception as if the try catch block does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the special variable $_

This small example shows how it works:

```
try {
  testmenow
} catch {
  Write-Host $_
}
```

$_ is an object so you can do

```
$_|gm
```

in the catch block in order to see the methods you can call.

Comment: larsgregersen, can you please improve your answer explaining what is $_|gm doing? what should I use only $_ ?